# Reducing Memory Usage When Storing Data In A Program - VB.NET / C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that stores 100,000+ numbers inside of it. Each number is 10 digits in length or smaller. The program itself has data input into it, of which it loops through the user input to see if any of their numbers are already in the array using `if ArrayList.Contains(userinput)`.

It would appear that when having an ArrayList of this size a LOT of memory is being used. Would there be a faster way to run this, E.g. Database or `If TextFile.Contains(Line)`?

Comment: If you store the numbers as strings in your list, you could start by storing them as numbers and it should decrease your memory usage significantly.

Comment: Are you concerned in speed or in memory usage? Please, choose which is more important. As for memory, a 100000-item `ArrayList` of `int`s should consume about 1.5 Mb. A 100000-item array of 10-character strings should be about 3-5 Mb. Are you sure you have memory usage issues and only **one** `ArrayList` instance?

Comment: I am actually running multiple threads that are constantly checking to see if the list contains X number, each thread is SyncLocked & the ArrayList is being ammended as new unique numbers come into play. I'll give the List<T>, BinarySearch & storing as Integers a try, how can you add to an ArrayList by Type?

Comment: 1. You haven't answered if you're interested in speed or memory usage. 2. So, the `ArrayList` is a shared resource??? That's an important detail that you should add to the question. 3. This detail should not noticably affect the memory usage.

Comment: I cannot 'add by Type'. I meant that I just created an `ArrayList` and added `int`s or `string`s to it in a loop. I've checked: a 10-million-items `ArrayList` of `int`s consumes about 160 Mb. My estimates were quite good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a `List<T>` to avoid boxing and save memory.
Using a `HashSet<T>` will be much faster, but will use a little more memory than a `List<T>`.

Depending on your precise scenario, a database would probably be best.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution could be have array of `100.000+` elements in *sorted order* and use `BinarySearch` to find an element of interest.

Mush faster then `Contains` does and you do not need allocation of dictionary, so no additional memory consuption.

All these stuff is a subject for *measuring* to pick the right choice for you in *your concrete scenario*.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you have a concurrent read/write scenario, consider using `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<,>`. It should provide better performance since it doesn't require locks around it's operations. However, if the operations are more complex than simple add/get/remove, then you'll still need locks and a `HashSet<>` should be faster (as SLaks has suggested).